# How to command pv (Pipe Viewer) to work with diff?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, grep, diff

using:
OS: Kubuntu `22.04.3` LTS x86_64
diff (GNU diffutils) `3.8`  Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
pv `1.8.0`  Copyright 2023 Andrew Wood, pv = Pipe Viewer

commands to display above:
`neofetch --stdout |grep 'OS:'`
`diff --version`
`pv   --version`

.

cmd1 below is working fine:
`time  diff -rq --no-dereference "$dir1" "$dir2" && echo "no difference" || echo "differences!"`

.

If cmd1 above takes hours to compare 2 directories
then it would be nice, not essential,
to have an estimate of time till done compare.
ETA ~ estimate time of arrival = compare done.

.

cmd2 below, does not work:
`diff -rqs "$dir1" "$dir2" |pv -s $(du -bc "$dir1" |tail -1 |cut -f 1) |grep -v "^Files .* identical$" > /tmp/logfile_diff_compare1.txt`

With cmd2, above,
if all compares OK
then the output to a text file is `0` bytes, meaning
/tmp/logfile_diff_compare1.txt
is a zero byte text file = no difference = 100% compare is OK.

.

note1:
output of cmd2 at about 40% done of a 3 hour compare:

```
# 50.4MiB 1:12:57 [0.00  B/s] [>                                                    ]  0% ETA 0:00:00
```

.

note2: the
`ETA 0:00:00`
but should be about 2 hours

.

note3:

```
1263856953223 = bytes in source directory dir1 or
1263.9 GB     =       in source directory dir1 or
   1.2 TB     =       in source directory dir1
```

.

reference:
Some more progress and ETA tricks
https://assafmo.github.io/2018/06/16/more-progress-eta.html

```
➜  joincap *.pcap | pv -s $(du -bc *pcap | tail -1 | cut -f 1) > merged.pcap 
1.16GiB 0:00:04 [ 275MiB/s] [============>                    ] 38% ETA 0:00:06
```

.

Question:
How to command pv (Pipe Viewer) to work with diff?

--

Comment: Untested idea : `diff file1 <(pv file2) && echo "no difference" || echo "differences!"`

Comment: @harrymc Making `pv` work with `diff` is easy. Making `pv` work with `diff -r` is (almost?) impossible; *this* is what the OP wants to do. Unfortunately your idea is useless for `diff -r`.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: Right, I missed out on the recursive part. This will probably need a script, perhaps used with the [eta command](https://github.com/aioobe/eta/wiki/eta-man-page). But it doesn't seem very simple.